# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: exception for DefaultItemAnimator$2.class

Tags: android, appodeal

I have been tired after trying to solve this problem for last 2 days. My project was OK before implementing Appodeal. But after implementing Appodeal this error is occurred. I have seen several solution for the same type problem. But I didn't get solution for duplicate entry of DefaultItemAnimator$2.class

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$2.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem:
After deleting support-v7.jar from libs folder it's working. actually support-v7 was duplicate.